# WebRequestExtensions.GetCurrentNetworkInterface throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to get `Network Interface` on which `HttpWebRequest` was made

I found [WebRequestExtensions.GetCurrentNetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.webrequestextensions.getcurrentnetworkinterface%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) function for this. `HttpWebRequest` also has `GetCurrentNetworkInterface()` method to perform the same.

This is my code:

```
 HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(Url, UriKind.Absolute)); 
 //this line throws InvalidOperationException       
 NetworkInterfaceInfo i = httpWebRequest.GetCurrentNetworkInterface();
```

I perform method call from UI thread. If I made call after `BeginGetResponse` exception tells "request was finished". What is workaround for this?

Exception info:

Message is `InvalidOperationException`

StackTrace:

```
  at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.GetConnectionDetails(IntPtr& Details, Int32& sizeofDetails)
  at Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.WebRequestExtensions.GetCurrentNetworkInterface(WebRequest request)
```

Comment: And let me guess, the `InvalidOperationException` message was completely blank, since you didn't post it?

Comment: Yup. Only `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want this information?

Comment: It's for application that performs connection measurements, so I need to know what connection type was used in this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(Url, UriKind.Absolute));

httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(result =>
{
    // Handle response
}, null);

var info = WebRequestExtensions.GetCurrentNetworkInterface(httpWebRequest);
```

I had a similar problem recently and found you can't call `GetCurrentNetworkInterface` before `BeginGetResponse` (because the connection hasn't been made) but if you call it **within** the `BeginGetResponse` callback the request has already completed and you get the "Web request is already finished" error.

**ADDED by question-starter:**

Fully-worker code which allows to get `NetworkInterfaceInfo` of `HttpWebRequest` from background thread (used `BackgroundWorker` in this example to simulate this):

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, 4) =>
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com", UriKind.Absolute));

    EventWaitHandle Wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(result =>
    {
        Wait.Set();
    }, null);

    Wait.WaitOne();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {                        
        var info = WebRequestExtensions.GetCurrentNetworkInterface(httpWebRequest);
        MessageBox.Show(info.InterfaceType.ToString());
    });
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**ADDED AFTER FULL-DAY DEBUGGING:**
I can't make it work 100% time, especially when loaded page is small. In this situation "request is finished" appears all the time. But with large loaded page it works even without `EventWaitHandle`

Comment: Yes, I see the same. Example from msdn also has try/catch where they get network info, so it seems that they also can't get it...

Comment: The above code works for me though.  In the real code I do put it in a try/catch because I suppose it's possible that the UI thread could be blocked long enough that the response returns before the information is retrieved.

Comment: Thanks, man. I thought, I tried put this line everywhere, but this works!

Comment: Yes, I suppose with a very quick request the request may complete before the info is retrieved. I've just had a quick look at the MSDN article and it states in the code comments **"It may complete before you call GetCurrentNetworkInterface. Replace this with a longer-running request if needed"** which seems a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you might want to take a look at the [NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) Property. The documentation says that it returns the Interface type that is servicing current internet requests.

If this is not what you are looking for, you might also want to try the [DeviceNetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class(I suspect you might have already looked at this option.). I think you could use the IsCellularDataEnabled and The IsWifiEnabled static properties.

Comment: `NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType` is not applicable for me, because I use network requirements, so the query performed not on default network interface. Also, I need `NetworkInterfaceInfo` for use in `ResolveHostNameAsync` which has this parameter. How I can get it in another way? Sockets, which I used as a workaround before, also have a problem that I found today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294527/connect-socket-under-lock-screen-on-windows-phone