# Connect socket under lock screen on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to write application that connects to a server with a sockets. All works fine, but when application is running under lock screen the socket can't connect (it is waiting while lock screen is removed).

Device connected to a PC, so WiFi should not have an impact (auto turn-off) for battery-saving

How to reproduce (code below):

1) Start application and wait 30 seconds. In Debug windows you will see:

```
Try to connect at 15:35:08
Connected at 15:35:08
```

2) Start application, lock the screen and wait 30 seconds. In Debug windows you will see:

```
Try to connect at 15:36:07
Connected at 15:36:42
```

So, during lock screen nothing happens, socket is frozen

This is my code my:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

        DnsEndPoint dnsEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint("stackoverflow.com", 80);
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketOperationEventArguments = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketOperationEventArguments.RemoteEndPoint = dnsEndPoint;
        socketOperationEventArguments.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success && e.ConnectSocket.Connected)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Connected at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
        };

        DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer()
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
        Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Try to connect at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            socket.ConnectAsync(socketOperationEventArguments);

            Timer.Stop();
        };
        Timer.Start();
    }
```

EDIT:

Send data is also not working under lock screen. Log:

```
Try to connect at 10:18:39
Connected at 10:18:39
Try to send at 10:18:40
Send data at 10:18:40
Try to send at 10:18:41
Send data at 10:18:41
Try to send at 10:18:42
Send data at 10:18:42
Try to send at 10:18:43
Try to send at 10:18:44
Try to send at 10:18:45
Try to send at 10:18:46
Try to send at 10:18:47
Try to send at 10:18:48
Try to send at 10:18:49
Send data at 10:18:50
Send data at 10:18:50
Send data at 10:18:50
Send data at 10:18:50
Send data at 10:18:50
Send data at 10:18:50
Send data at 10:18:50
Try to send at 10:18:51
Send data at 10:18:51
Try to send at 10:18:52
Send data at 10:18:52
```

Screen was locked from 10:18:43 to 10:18:50

Comment: If the socket is already open before the lock screen is activated does it remain open?

Comment: Nop, all send data `Completed` events are raised when screen lock is removed. While lock, there are nothing...

Comment: If you look at [MSDN's Idle Detection for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)  there's a checklist for Silverlight Applications. Item 7 on that list is; "Signal your application that new network requests and isolated storage operations should not be performed." It's not explicitly stated, but I'd wager that all network connectivity is disabled whilst under the lock screen. Try opening a connection before the lock, leave it running, and see what happens once locked / relocked.

Comment: `Socket` can't send data even if was connected before lock. But, `HttpWebRequest` work fine under lock screen. Why there is such restriction on sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are not receiving any data when Lock Screen is activated in Mango.
There is no known workaround for that.

See more info here:

http://irc7.org/index.php/2011/09/07/why-doesnt-irc7-run-under-lock-screen/

What you could do is try to prevent the Lock Screen to come up in the first place.
See here for more info on how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: I saw this link, but I hope that some workaround is exists. Thanks anyway